# oData deserialization issue in application

Tags: c#, json, wpf, odata, json-deserialization

I have an odata service that I am referencing in a WPF app. It seems to have an issue deserializing some things. For example, the query below always returns Host as null.

```
var results = _container.HostVersions.Expand(hv => hv.Host)
                                   .Expand(hv => hv.Version.Service)
                                   .Where(hv => hv.Version.Id == versionId &&
                                          hv.Version.Service.Id == serviceId);
```

However, if you take the generated resulting URL from this query and paste it in the browser, the JSON shows the Host object. As well, I know the Host object is in the database. So basically for some reason not all of the objects in the Expand call are being deserialized in the application. I have had no luck searching for this issue either on google or on this site. Hoping someone has run into this before.

EDIT:

So before I make the above call, I make this call:

```
var result = _container.HostVersions
            .Expand(hv => hv.Host)
            .Expand(x => x.Version.Service.Versions)
            .Where(hv => hv.Host.ServerFarmEnvironment.EnvironmentId == environmentId &&
                    hv.Host.ServerFarmEnvironment.ServerFarmId == serverFarmId);
```

If I put the Expand for Host in there, as seen above, then call the first method in this post, Host is populated. But if I remove the Host expand from this call, the first method in this post has null for Host. It really is so bizarre. Fiddler shows that both responses are the same, as I suspected since the URL resolve properly for the odata. So it has to be some weird deserialization issue that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 possible issues.

Your DataServiceContext can be out of date, have you tried re-generating if from the current project version of OData service? If some properties on the Host class do not match or if the namespace has changed/does not match - the Expand won't be able to get any of the objects of the type Host.

Also you can check if Host class namespace is recognized by client. You can do this by grabbing all Host objects from the service (if your schema allows this) or alternatively create a query for host type objects on your service which will return one or more testing Host instances. If those won't also work - you need to fix namespace recognition issues.

Another issue might be MaxExpansionDepth set to 0 or other permissions limits.

Comment: 1. It is up to date.
2. I can see all Host records when I just query _container.Hosts.
3. Max Depth is at like 6 I believe.

I've checked all these things. It really is the strangest thing. I forgot to mention that this isn't a problem in a sample WinForm and Console app that I tried it in. Just in this one WPF app I have.

Comment: How about checking (maybe posting) what's being sent and received using fiddler? A pro tip (if you don't know it yet): fiddler can handle .fiddler domain automatically so changing your url to http://localhost.fiddler/service/thisisme.svc would allow you to check raw packets for suspicious headers.

Comment: Also if you are using Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider check for recent updates of this package and try running Update-Package Microsoft.Data.OData , it might be a bug.

Comment: So I figured out a way to make it work, but it isn't ideal. That said, I did a fiddler trace when I made it work and when I made it so it wouldn't work. The raw responses for both are completely identical other than the time stamps obviously. So it seems like it must be some weird deserialization issue once it gets into the .net app.